# bad_alloc with QVector but not with std::vector

Tags: c++, qt4.8

I guess it's not so much a question but a request for comments.

Today I was trying to load a larger dataset into my software and encountered a couple of bad allocs.

So the code in question looks like this.

```
QVector<float>verts;
try
{
    verts.reserve( numPoints * 6 );
}
catch ( std::bad_alloc& )
{
    qDebug() << "error";
}
```

numPoints in this case is 92911773 so it'll try to allocate numpoints * 6 * sizeof( float ) = 2,214,922,152 bytes. My machine runs a 64bit linux with 12Gb ram. So this shouldn't be a problem.

So this throws the bad_alloc exception. Now if I change the QVector to an std::vector it works. Can anyone comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the definition of `QVector`, I'm going to guess that it is because Qt uses an `int` to represent the size.

Your vector's size is big enough that an int will overflow, so the allocation fails.

`std::vector` does the correct (and sane) thing, and uses a `size_t` to represent the size, so it doesn't overflow.

Comment: Doh could've seen that myself.

Comment: log(6 * 92911773)/log(2) = 29.05..., so the mere item count should comfortably fit inside a 32-bit int

Comment: Seems, the QVector-internals are also 32-bit limitted :-/

Comment: Not 32bit but int limited i guess

Comment: So I come to the conclusion, while the number of elements fits into an int, it probably uses int for the memory allocation as well, which will be a negative number here thus the bad alloc.

Comment: @TilmanVogel yeah, so apparently QVector allocates an array of bytes, not ints.

Comment: @jalf Qt as general wasn't designed to be 64bit ,  it wasn't changed until Qt6 and the way it is done creates portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed in Qt6: all containers have 64 bits size.
https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlist.html#more-information-on-using-qt-containers